# Mongoose ignoring part of object unless defined as Schema.Types.Mixed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

Sorry for the coffee-script.

Pulling my hair out with this one.  I have a schema similar to this:

```
reviewSchema = Schema
  title: String
  meta: 
    author: String
    date: String
  article: String
  tags: [
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ref: "Tag"
  ]
  images: [
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ref: "Image"
  ]
  attr: 
    appearance: String
    aroma: String
    flavor: String
    from: String
    grade: String
    lineage: String
    name: String
    overall: String
    packaging: String
    pickupdate: String
    price: String
    reason: String
    story: String
    type: String
Review = mongoose.model 'Review', reviewSchema
```

I also have some data which I have assembled into some JSON files with corresponding data.  When I go to make a new schema I look into that file and grab the JSON and create a new review object by:

thisReview = new Review json, minimize: false

If I console.log the json prior to creating 'thisReview' I see that my 'attr' key is properly filled with data but if I console.log 'thisReview' or check the database, I receive NO results for the 'attr' key of my documents.  'attr' is completely ignored.

I went as far as making sure each JSON file's JSON.attr object had each key from the schema with a "" (empty) string for those which didn't exist.  The other nested objects like the meta object of the schema are populating perfectly.

Any idea what is happening?

Extra Info: When I get rid of the key/value pairs within the attr object and instead assign: 
    attr: Schema.Types.Mixed

Then all of the data is successfully saved including the empty ("") strings.

Any help would be **much** appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` property of `attr` is likely tripping up Mongoose to thinking `attr` is a string instead of an embedded object.  Use a more explicit definition for the property, like this:

```
attr: 
    appearance: String
    aroma: String
    flavor: String
    from: String
    grade: String
    lineage: String
    name: String
    overall: String
    packaging: String
    pickupdate: String
    price: String
    reason: String
    story: String
    type:
        type: String
```

Comment: You are my favorite person of the day! I was looking for keywords and I don't know how I overlooked this.  Thanks so much.